# Generic applet style system for publishing mathematics demonstrations?

Tags: math, web-applications

Anyone who's tried to study mathematics using online resources will have come across these Java applets that demonstrate a particular mathematical idea. Examples:

- http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/java/Mobius.html
- http://www.mathcs.org/java/programs/FFT/index.html

I love the idea of this interactive approach because I believe it is very helpful in conveying mathematical principles.

I'd like to create a system for visually designing and publishing these 'mathlets' such that they can be created by teachers with little programming experience.

So in order to create this app, i'll need a GUI and a 'math engine'. I'll probably be working with .NET because thats what I know best and i'd like to start experimenting with F#. Silverlight appeals to me as a presentation framework for this project (im not worried about interoperability right now).

So my questions are:

- does anything like this exist already in full form?
- are there any GUI frameworks for displaying mathematical objects such as graphs & equations?
- are there decent open source libraries that exposes a mathematical framework (Math.NET looks good, just wondering if there is anything else out there)
- is there any existing work on taking mathematical models/demos built with maple/matlab/octave/mathematica etc and publishing them to the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at [Wolfram demonstrations](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/), and at the mathematica web player. This lets you take a Mathematica file and run it from a browser, and the demonstrations site already has thousands of demonstrations.

Comment: Looks good, except it appears you cant control the applets from the web? All the demos seem to be pre-recorded, and can only be actively controlled if you download them and run them locally. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. It'd be hard to convince Wolfram to let people use Mathematica for free (oh, wait, Wolfram|Alpha). In any case, you should look to see if your needs aren't satisfied by what's already there.

Another thing I'd *really* suggest looking at is SAGE (http://www.sagemath.org). That's a free/open source mathematica competitor which is pretty good and has a very nice web interface.

Comment: Whilst the graphical demonstrations look good, they arent of much use to me if they cant be run (or created) from the web. The online Sage Notebook looks great, but again - it seems lacking in the interactive visualisation department. For instance, is it possible to create/manipulate any of these interactions within the online Sage environment? http://wiki.sagemath.org/interact

Comment: The source code is provided specifically for that purpose. I don't know about how easy it is to embed these standalone from the online notebook, but at least there's something to start from. And, the online notebook isn't too scary.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for, but I'm going to accept this as answer as it seems the closest thing out there.